# Share files between laptops without prior network connection

Tags: windows, networking, laptop, wireless-networking

Is it possible to somehow connect two computers together and create a temporary network between them to share files? Every now and again me and a few other people need to share files, but there aren't any networks to connect to, and removable media is not really an option.

Sometimes we have used a cross-over ethernet cable to transfer files, but obviously this only scales when there are only two laptops. Someone suggested using USB with a USB hub, but that does not sound like it would work. Is there something similar, except for wi-fi?

All the laptops are Windows, with varying versions (although most being Vista) being used. Although I am really keen on getting it to work with just Windows laptops, cross platform solutions are even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You need to create something that is called an "Ad Hoc Network". You are not mentioning the OS of your laptops, you can easily search for it on google. For windows XP for example, here is a guide:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/setup/adhoc.mspx

Comment: My apologies. I meant to include that they are Windows laptops.

Comment: If they all have wifi adapters this works great, regardless of OS. Can even work with "smart phone" type devices as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bluetooth adapter on laptops then you can create Personal Area Network. Its described [here.](http://hubpages.com/hub/How-To-Create-A-Personal-Area-Network-Using-Bluetooth)